# Exercise 12 page 40 Conway's FA book

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to do the following exercise from Conway's FA :

> Let $μ$ = Area measure on $D={\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|<l}\}$ and define $Α: L^2(μ) \to L^2(μ)$ by $(Af)(z) = zf(z)$ for $|z| < 1$ and $f$ in $L^2(μ)$. Find a nontrivial reducing subspace for $A$ and an invariant subspace that does not reduce $A$.

My attempt : First I need to construct a subspace $M$ of $L^2(μ)$ s.t. ... ; however, how subspace of $L^2(μ)$ does look like? After that, the question has actually two parts : 1. Finding $M_1$ s.t. $AM_1 \subset M_1$ and $A (M_1)^{\perp} \subset (M_1)^{\perp}$ ; 2. Finding $M_2$ s.t. $AM_2 \subset M_2$ but $A (M_2)^{\perp} \notsubset (M_2)^{\perp}$. So, if $\int |f|^2 dμ < \infty$ then $\int |zf|^2 dμ < \infty$ so $M_1=L^2(μ)$ holds for part 1?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that in Conway's the term "(linear) subspace" is used to mean a closed linear subspace.

> Let $\mu = $ Area measure on $\Bbb D= \{z \in \Bbb C : |z|<1\}$ and define $A: L^2(\mu) \rightarrow L^2(\mu)$ by $(Af)(z)=zf(z)$ for $|z|<1$ and $f$ in $L^2(\mu)$.  Find a nontrivial reducing space for $A$ and an invariant subspace that does not reduce $A$.

**Proof**: We know that $L^2(\mu)$ is a Hilbert space and it is easy to see that $A$ is a bounded linear transformation from $L^2(\mu)$ to $L^2(\mu)$. In fact $\|A\|\leq 1$.

The trivial reducing space are $\{0\}$ and $L^2(\mu)$. Let us find nontrivial reducing spaces.

Let $E \subseteq \Bbb D$ such that $\mu(E)>0$ and $\mu(\Bbb D \setminus E)>0$. Let
$$M=\{f \in L^2(\mu): f=0 \text { a.e. in } \Bbb D \setminus E  \}$$
It is easy to see that $M$ is a closed linear subspace of $L^2(\mu)$ and that
$$M^\perp=\{ f \in L^2(\mu): f=0 \text { a.e. in } E\}$$
It is easy to see that $A(M)\subseteq M$ and $A(M^\perp)\subseteq M^\perp$. So $M$ is a reducing space for $A$.

Now, let $N=\{f \in L^2(\mu): f(z) \text{ is a polynomial in } z\}$
$N$ is a non-closed linear subspace of $L^2(\mu)$ (in Conway's terminology, a non-closed linear submanifold of  $L^2(\mu)$).

Let $g: \Bbb D \rightarrow \Bbb C$ be the function defined by $g(z)= \bar{z}$. It is immediate that $g \in  L^2(\mu)$, $g \ne 0$ and, for all $n \in \Bbb N$,
$$\int_{\Bbb D} z^n \overline{g(z)} d\mu(z) = \int_{\Bbb D} z^{n+1} d\mu(z)=0$$
So, for all $f \in N$,
$\int_{\Bbb D} f \bar{g} d\mu =0$. Since $g \ne 0$, we have that $N$ is not dense in  $L^2(\mu)$. In fact, $N \subseteq \{cg \in L^2(\mu): c \in \Bbb C\}^\perp$ and $\{cg \in L^2(\mu): c \in \Bbb C\}^\perp$ ia a closed proper subset of $L^2(\mu)$.

Let $\overline{N}$ be the closure of $N$ in $L^2(\mu)$. So, $\overline{N}$ is a proper (closed) linear subspace of $L^2(\mu)$ and, for all $f \in \overline{N}$,
$\int_{\Bbb D} f \bar{g} d\mu =0$, that is,  $g \in \overline{N}^\perp$.

Now, it is clear that $A(N) \subseteq N$, and since $A$ is continuous,
$A(\overline{N}) \subseteq \overline{N}$. So $\overline{N}$ is invariant for $A$.

Using proposition 3.7 of chapter 2, to prove that $\overline{N}$ does not reduce $A$ , it is enough to prove that $\overline{N}$ is not invariant for $A^*$.

It is easy to see that $(A^*f)(z) = \bar{z} f(z)$. Let $1$ be the constant polynomial whose value is $1$. Then $1 \in N \subseteq  \overline{N}$.

Now, to get a contradiction suppose that $\overline{N}$ is invariant for $A^*$. Then $g= A^*1 \in \overline{N}$. But $g \in \overline{N}^\perp$, so $g=0$. Contradiction, because $g \ne 0$. So, we have that $\overline{N}$ is not invariant for $A^*$ and so, $\overline{N}$ does not reduce $A$. $\square$